# Tooltip Container Not found Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm getting the following error:

> **You should set Tooltip container. Tooltip.For(container)**

My MVC Razor code is:

```
<span id="TrippleCol1Line2Help" class="fa fa-info-circle helpIcon">&nbsp;</span>
(@Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
               .For("#TrippleCol1Line2Help")
               .Position(@TooltipPosition.Top)
               .Width(@LayoutDefaultCssClasses.HelpToolTipWidth)
               .ShowOn(@TooltipShowOnEvent.Click)
               .Content("Help Text"))
```

Somehow, I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra at signs (`@`) from your code, and make sure the first `@` is before the parenthesis:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
           .For("#TrippleCol1Line2Help")
           .Position(TooltipPosition.Top)
           .Width(LayoutDefaultCssClasses.HelpToolTipWidth)
           .ShowOn(TooltipShowOnEvent.Click)
           .Content("Help Text"))
```

Comment: Make sure the first `@` is before the parenthesis. I tested this. It works. The only thing is that I don't know what `LayoutDefautCssClasses` is. I just used Width(120), instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it was something simple.